# Repeat row with only four columns in html table using angular 4

Tags: angular4-forms

For Ex. I have an arraylike this cids:Array=[{Id:1},{Id:2},{Id:3},{Id:4},{Id:5},{Id:6},{Id:7}---------etc..]

I want output as :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9
```

Using *ngFor in angular 4

Comment: For more readability, you can use "code" markdown for the line : Array=[{Id:1},{Id:2},{Id:3},{Id:4},{Id:5},{Id:6},{Id:7}---------etc..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert your arrray[] in array[][4]. And then you will be able to use an  imbricated ngFor  (ngFor in another ngFor)

Pseudo code :

```
ngFor* {
   ngFor* {
      print value;
      insert a space;
   }
  Insert a return line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span *ngFor="let cid of cids">
    {{cid.Id}}
    <br *ngIf="(cid.Id)%4==0" />
</span>
```